# asynchronous resource intensive design pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, asynchronous, web-crawler

I am writing a Web Crawler in java, with the following design pattern:

I separated the task into atomic subtasks:

```
- downloading
- content separation
- html parsing
- pdf parsing
- link extraction
- etc.
```

Each subtask has an input of a predefined type, and can have any number of different outputs. Available data types are:

```
- link
- binary data
- raw html
- raw pdf
- parsed document
- etc.
```

eg: "downloading" task has an input type of link, and outputs binary data, while "content separation" has an input type of binary data, and outputs either a "raw html" or a "raw pdf" object.

There is a worker pool of N threads that executes these subtasks. Every time there is a free worker (an idle thread), the data type with the highest number of objects is selected (eg: there are 5 links, 2 binary data, and 6 parsed documents in the database then "parsed document" data type is selected). Then a subtask with the selected data type is created and executed asynchronously by the worker.

The purpose of this design, is to keep the implementation of the crawler itself as simple as possible (only need to define the data types and the subtasks, everything else including multithreading is handled by the "container").

Thats about it in nutshell.

I am pretty sure that im not the first one to think of this sollution, but i cant seem to find anything on the topic.
Is there any name for this design pattern, or can anyone share some articles about it? If there is an existing open source java implementation of it, or anyone knows of a project that works like this, that would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you describe a Message Based Communication. [See for example Asynchronous Queuing](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/asynchronous_queuing)

Your described design rembers me of a hot-pool even though it is not exactly the same.

**Edit**

In my Opinion everything you need is already provided by Java.

Java provides [ThreadPools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) and Java provides [Priority Blocking Queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html). In my opinion this should be enough. Isn't it?

Maybe you give the [ProducerConsumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) as well as the [ThreadPool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) a read. I hope this will be sufficient.

Comment: I am using asynchronous queuing as a part of my program, but its only a small part of the more complex system. I am looking for something closer to what i described.

Comment: @Kicsi Could you maybe specify what you are exactly looking for? I thought you would be looking for an implementation of that worker pool? Or are you looking an implementation of a crawler?

Comment: what i am looking for is a framework/container where i only need to define the subtasks and the datatypes, and everything works as i described. Im not necessarily looking for an implementation, any proof that some1 did this before me is fine (just need a starting point for searching :)). Implementing this system is not so hard, but testing it and finding all the possible errors/shortcomings and fine tuning it in general is a long an painful process, which id like to avoid if possible.